# Custom theorem-style environment

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, theorems

I use LaTeX to typeset notes and case briefs for law school. So far I have settled for a theorem-style layout for each case using `thmtools`. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of cases}

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={case}]
\chapter{1}
\begin{case}[name=Case name]

\textbf{Facts}: foo.

\textbf{Issue}: bar.

\textbf{Rule}: foobar.

\textbf{Analysis}: fob.

\textbf{Conclusion}: bor.
\end{case}
%repeat ad nauseum
\end{document}
```

### Specific issues

1. **Case structured and defined by a LaTeX macro:** Typing `\textbf{Facts}` and the rest is tedious for every case. Is there a way to define a specialized theorem-like environment that will simplify the matter? For example, I am vaguely familiar with the `moderncv` package and I know that the six braces in the command `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}` can be filled with different information with different formatting. Would it be possible to define some similar theorem-like environment where I could do, for example, `\case{Case name}{foo.}{bar.}{foobar.}{fob.}{bor.}` and get the same output as in my MWE? If so, how could I define this environment?
2. **Table of cases:** If this is possible, would it then be possible to print a list of case names with content from one of the braces appended to each case? Right now I have `\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={case}]` which spits out a list of cases. But I'd rather have a list of cases with the `foo.` from each case appended to it. Might that be possible?

Comment: (1) is certainly doable. I don't exactly know what you mean by (2). Could you provide some sample output?

Comment: @Werner Let's say I have two cases. Case 1 is called `A v. B` and has `I am a dog` in the first set of braces. Case 2 is called `C v. D` and has `I am a cat` in the first set of braces. I would like some way to print `A v. B: I am a dog` and then `C v. D: I am a cat` with one command. I have the command `\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={case}]` so far, but that only does half the work by spitting out the case names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that you could use as a start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printcases}{\@starttoc{cse}}
\newcommand{\l@case}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1.5em}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\case}[6]{%
\addcontentsline{cse}{case}{#1: #2}
\begin{description}
  \item[Case]: #1
  \item[Facts]: #2
  \item[Issue]: #3
  \item[Rule]: #4
  \item[Analysis]: #5
  \item[Conclusion]: #6
\end{description}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
% \case{<name>}{<facts>}{<issue>}{<rule>}{<analysis>}{<conclusion>}
\case{Case name}{foo.}{bar.}{foobar.}{fob.}{bor.}
\case{Case name}{bar.}{bar.}{foobar.}{fob.}{bor.}
\case{Case name}{baz.}{bar.}{foobar.}{fob.}{bor.}

\printcases
\end{document}
```

Each `case` is set using a `description` (list-like) environment, allowing it to be broken at the page boundary (if needed). Additionally, each case name and page number is written to a ToC-like file (extension `.cse`) and printed using `\printcases`.

Comment: is it possible to remove the space between the word and the colon? Right now the output is `Case :` and I was wondering how I might change that to `Case:`.

Comment: @longstreth: Yes; that's the so-called `\labelsep` of the list `description`. Add `\usepackage{enumitem}` to your document preamble and use `\begin{description}[labelsep=0pt]`. Alternatively, to get a **bold** colon **:**, use `\item[Case:]`.